# Tikz: Problem with tiny distance between line segments

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I want to create a metro-map like picture that shows some data flows. Since I want to have diagonal, horizontal and vertical lines in several thickness and colors I need to draw curved connections between the lines. My idea to do this is to provide macros with simple and intuitive names, for example: twelve-to-three, meaning coming from above and bend 90 degrees to left and so on.. I use pdftolatex and have the problem that there is a minimal distance which disturbes me :-) Minimal working example enclosed. What should I do to get around the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4paper, landscape]{article}
%----------------------------------------------------------
% Template: METRO PLAN
%----------------------------------------------------------

%Seitenraender anzeigen und aendern
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
  left=0.5cm,
  right=0.5cm,
  top=0.5cm,
  bottom=0.5cm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


% We need the following libraries for TikZ here:
\usetikzlibrary {positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  %maybe can be dropped later :-)


\begin{document} 


%Layer-Technologie: 
\pgfdeclarelayer{bottomlayer}   
\pgfdeclarelayer{middlelayer}    
\pgfdeclarelayer{toplayer}      

\pgfsetlayers{main,bottomlayer,middlelayer,toplayer}     


% Background color
\pagecolor{white}
\color{black} 

\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=0.1cm and 0.1cm ] 

\begin{pgfonlayer}{toplayer} 


% Invisible Node: 
%USAGE: \invnodeXXXXX{Node-ID}{REF-Node-ID}{xshift}{yshift}
\newcommand{\invnodedown}[4] { 
\node[coordinate](#1) [below=of #2,xshift=#3 cm, yshift= #4 cm]{};}


\newcommand{\twelvetothreefat}[2] { 
\draw [line width=0.35cm,color=#2] (#1.center) arc (-180:-90:1);}  %end of macro
\newcommand{\fatline}[3] { 
\tikzstyle {style_fatline}=   [line width=0.35cm,color=#3]
\draw  [style_fatline]   (#2) -- (#1)  ;}  %end of macro
\node (ROOT){x}; 

\invnodedown{INV10}{ROOT}{0}{-3};
\fatline{INV10}{ROOT}{red}
\twelvetothreefat{INV10}{red}

\end{pgfonlayer}  


\begin{pgfonlayer}{middlelayer}  
%------------maybe later used--
\end{pgfonlayer}  


\begin{pgfonlayer}{bottomlayer} 
%...reserved to draw colored areas...
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please fix your code? It seems that all `[` have become `\[` and all `]` `\]`, and there is some `[![` before `\begin{document}` and some stuff after `\end{document}`. (And `fillcolor` should probably just be `fill'.)

Comment: Sorry, have fixed the MWE :-)

Comment: I have no real solution, but I also don't understand why you do not just draw the full thing in one stretch. `\draw[line width=0.35cm,red] (ROOT)--(INV10) arc (-180:-90:1);` does not have the micro-gap.

Comment: Ah perfect! - Yes thats a good solution with one stretch. I just tried to do with macros because of an intuitive and reusable way and not always juggling with degrees :-) I try to change the macro and bring the arc inside and draw in one stretch...That should give the same result I guess...Thank you for your advice, marmot - very helpful!

Comment: Just another minor comment: defining a tikzstyle inside a command like you do does, arguably, not make too much sense. You ask Ti*k*Z to redefine the style over and over whenever you call the command, and this only to change a color. Of course, this may make sense if you intend to set the color that is to be used by other commands.

Comment: Also `\tikzstyle` is deprecated and should be avoided in new code. use `\tikzset` instead.

Comment: Note that `\somemacro{}{}{}{}` is much harder for a user (including you) to remember than something using a key-value interface, because you must remember an arbitrary order. In general, turning a key-value interface into many-argument macros is a step towards greater opacity and error-proneness. That's why key-value interfaces have proved increasingly popular: the slight increase in verbosity is more than compensated for by savings in time and frustration elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable and many helpful hints and tricks. I now have a macro with one more option where I can give the length and the micro-gap disappears since I 'do the thing in one stretch'. I changed the \tikzstyle to \tikzset  and the \macros have been put into separate (library and reusable) files but have an example in the main tex-file...Thank you all ...Now I can proceed with the main task :-) Anyway I will inspect the hint with key-value interface, maybe they are the right thing for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I see no gap. Here's an edited version of your code, with `\tikzset` rather than the deprecated `\tikzstyle`. In my opinion, the “Setup” part should be in the document preamble, but that depends on several factors.

I add two screenshots, one at very high resolution, one lower. Previewers might show “gaps” at low resolutions, but it's only a side effect of rasterization. I used two different colors in order to maximize the possible effect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
%----------------------------------------------------------
% Template: METRO PLAN
%----------------------------------------------------------

%Seitenraender anzeigen und aendern
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
  left=0.5cm,
  right=0.5cm,
  top=0.5cm,
  bottom=0.5cm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


% We need the following libraries for TikZ here:
\usetikzlibrary {positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  %maybe can be dropped later :-)
\begin{document} 


%Layer-Technologie: 
\pgfdeclarelayer{bottomlayer}   
\pgfdeclarelayer{middlelayer}    
\pgfdeclarelayer{toplayer}      

\pgfsetlayers{main,bottomlayer,middlelayer,toplayer}     


% Background color
\pagecolor{white}
\color{black} 

\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=0.1cm and 0.1cm ] 

\begin{pgfonlayer}{toplayer}
%%% Setup %%%
\tikzset{
  fatline/.style={line width=0.35cm,color=#1},
}
% Invisible Node: 
%USAGE: \invnodeXXXXX{Node-ID}{REF-Node-ID}{xshift}{yshift}
\newcommand{\invnodedown}[4]{%
  \node[coordinate](#1) [below=of #2,xshift=#3 cm, yshift= #4 cm]{};
}
\newcommand{\twelvetothreefat}[2]{%
  \draw [fatline=#2] (#1.center) arc (-180:-90:1);
}
\newcommand{\fatline}[3]{%
  \draw  [fatline=#3]   (#2) -- (#1)  ;
}
%%% End setup %%%
\node (ROOT){x};

\invnodedown{INV10}{ROOT}{0}{-3};
\fatline{INV10}{ROOT}{blue!80!green}
\twelvetothreefat{INV10}{green!80!blue}

\end{pgfonlayer}


\begin{pgfonlayer}{middlelayer}  
%------------maybe later used--
\end{pgfonlayer}  


\begin{pgfonlayer}{bottomlayer} 
%...reserved to draw colored areas...
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

### High resolution

[image]

### Low resolution

[image]